# Naive Bayes and Neural Network similarities and choice

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, bayesian

I have a large dataset available with 10 different inputs and 1 output. All the outputs and the input are discreet (LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH). I was thinking about creating a neural network for this problem, however when I am designing the network to have 3 different outputs (LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH) and use a softmax neuron I basically get a 'probability'. Am I correct?

That made me think that it is maybe better to try a Naive Bayes classifier, and thus ignoring the possible correlations between the input variables, however in a large dataset Naive Bayes shows promising results.

Is there a reason to pick Neural Networks over Bayes in this case? What is the reason to pick Neural Networks when you want a probability as output (using a softmax function in Neural Networks).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, with softmax activations in the output layer, you can interpret the outputs as probabilities.

A potential reason to pick artificial neural networks (ANN) over Naive Bayes is the possibility you mentioned: correlations between input variables.  Naive Bayes assumes that all input variables are independent.  If that assumption is not correct, then it can impact the accuracy of the Naive Bayes classifier.  An ANN with appropriate network structure can handle the correlation/dependence between input variables.